# Problem with module registration in asp.net mvc + angularJs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm hosting my app on IIS. Whenever I m assigning module in my header:

```
<html ng-app="shopModule">
```

I'm getting error in console that module can't be loaded. This is my whole _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <html ng-app="shopModule">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>ShopiNet - sklep bez sensu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="~/Scripts/shop-module.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("JavascriptInHead", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I m getting this error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: shopModule is not defined
>       at Users:12

**Solution**

As I said, my app was hosted on IIS. Whenever you are hosting on it, you need to install additional package that enables you to use statick files by IIS.

Thats all.

Comment: I think the problem is you're declaring it before angular script, try change the ng-app directive to the `<body ng-app="shopModule">` tag

Comment: I found, that my problem is whenever i m using <script src=[...]> I can't load my local .js files.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. The problem was that when you are hosting on IIS , you need to enable hosting static local items